# How to make pas this auth with rpython requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'https://www.boxtoplay.com/panel'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
site = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password))
print(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('h1'))
print(site.url)
```

This code doesn't want to pass the auth, the output is still the login page

Comment: u have invalid query for auth, it's must be POST to https://www.boxtoplay.com/en/login/authenticate?redirect=/panel with payload [emailLogin, passwordLogin and g-recaptcha-response]

Comment: @SergeyK can you send me an exemple please?

Comment: @Tromal open DevTools in chrome go network and do login and will find the request to https://www.boxtoplay.com/en-GB/login/authenticate

Comment: @MeT Already done that but even when i POST with the good payload: 
```python
payload = {
    'emailLogin': 'email',
    'passwordLogin': 'password',
    'g-recaptcha-response': '6LdAPhkUAAAAAM8ti4xyWIjJdO9ovhhy6sFlQH1N'
}
```
It doens't work